# Is better to have a RESTful WS or use script PHP in my server to acces to a database?

Tags: java, php, web-services, rest

Recently, I have developed a REST WS. but I am not able to find important differences between using scripts PHP in my server to access to a database or to have a RESTful WS in my server to access to the same database.

**EDIT**
I use this WS to access to a database in which I have information about all the users than use my WS. So, I don't know if exists any difference related on behaviour, velocity, perfomance, etc.

---

I mean, if I access my WS to access to a database using Java. Is Java only the diference?

Are there any advantages to change the behaviour of my server and implements it as a WS?

I don't know what is that a RESTful WS has to be better than a server in which we run scripts PHP.

Comment: Depends on what you want to achieve. I'll vote to close for primarily opinion-based.

Comment: @Fildor I have specified that I want to access to a database

Comment: That's not the point. Both ways lead to Rome. The question is which towns you want to visit on your way. I'm trying to say: If you just want to put a table from a DB to a Website, PHP may be perfectly fine. If you want to provide an API to access information in your DB for developers, you'd probably be better off making a RESTful WS.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might get this question downvoted, as it's not code related.

My 2 cents. No technology or approach is best 100% of the time. it deppends on the scenario. If you're not oppening your service to 3rd parties  it doesn't provide much sugar to be restful. If you know you won't provide an api but maybe you might launch an app afterwards, a restfull API would make it much more easier... if not the case, not really an advantage